GStreamer Nvidia Plugin error "file too short" using dustynv/deepstream:r35.4.1
I am creating a Dockerfile for an GStreamer app I have. I am using the following image :
FROM dustynv/deepstream:r35.4.1
I use the hardware : Jetson AGX ORIN.
I have the following tegra release : R35 (release), REVISION: 5.0, GCID: 35550185, BOARD: t186ref, EABI: aarch64...
I can compile the app without error using CMake, but when I start making request I get the following error message :
(gst-plugin-scanner:30): GStreamer-WARNING **: 09:03:30.211: Failed to load plugin [13/961]
b/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstnveglstreamsrc.so': /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstnveglstreamsrc.so: file too short                                          
                                                                                           (gst-plugin-scanner:30): GStreamer-WARNING **: 09:03:30.211: Failed to load plugin '/usr/li
b/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstnvtee.so': /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstnvtee.so: file too short                                                            
                                                                                           (gst-plugin-scanner:30): GStreamer-WARNING **: 09:03:30.211: Failed to load plugin '/usr/li
b/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstnvjpeg.so': /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstnvjpeg.so: file too short                                  
                                                                                           (gst-plugin-scanner:30): GStreamer-WARNING **: 09:03:30.212: Failed to load plugin '/usr/li
b/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstnvvidconv.so': /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstnvvidconv.so: file too short                            
                                                                                           (gst-plugin-scanner:30): GStreamer-WARNING **: 09:03:30.212: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstnvv4l2camerasrc.so': /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstnvv4l2camerasrc.so: file too short                
                                                                               
(gst-plugin-scanner:30): GStreamer-WARNING **: 09:03:30.212: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstnvarguscamerasrc.so': /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstnvarguscamerasrc.so: file too short              
                                                                                           (gst-plugin-scanner:30): GStreamer-WARNING **: 09:03:30.212: Failed to load plugin '/usr/li
b/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstnvcompositor.so': /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstnvcompositor.so: file too short                      
                                                                               
(gst-plugin-scanner:30): GStreamer-WARNING **: 09:03:30.212: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstnvvideosinks.so': /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstrea
mer-1.0/libgstnvvideosinks.so: file too short                                                                                                                 
(gst-plugin-scanner:30): GStreamer-WARNING **: 09:03:30.212: Failed to load plugin '/usr/li
b/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstnvegltransform.so': /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstr
eamer-1.0/libgstnvegltransform.so: file too short                                          

(gst-plugin-scanner:30): GStreamer-WARNING **: 09:03:30.212: Failed to load plugin '/usr/li
b/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstnvvideo4linux2.so': /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstr
eamer-1.0/libgstnvvideo4linux2.so: file too short                                          

(gst-plugin-scanner:30): GStreamer-WARNING **: 09:03:30.212: Failed to load plugin '/usr/li
b/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstnvivafilter.so': /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstream
er-1.0/libgstnvivafilter.so: file too short  

(gst-plugin-scanner:30): GStreamer-WARNING **: 09:03:30.212: Failed to load plugin '/usr/li
b/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstnvvideosink.so': /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstream
er-1.0/libgstnvvideosink.so: file too short  

(gst-plugin-scanner:30): GStreamer-WARNING **: 09:03:30.212: Failed to load plugin '/usr/li
b/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstnveglglessink.so': /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstre...

When I look at the plugins they indeed seem empty :
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10336 Aug  1  2023 libgstnavigationtest.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  27416 Nov 28  2023 libgstnetsim.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  43808 Nov 16  2018 libgstnrtp.so   
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      0 Aug  3  2023 libgstnvarguscamerasrc.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      0 Aug  3  2023 libgstnvcompositor.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      0 Aug  3  2023 libgstnvdrmvideosink.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      0 Aug  3  2023 libgstnveglglessink.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      0 Aug  3  2023 libgstnveglstreamsrc.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      0 Aug  3  2023 libgstnvegltransform.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      0 Aug  3  2023 libgstnvivafilter.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      0 Aug  3  2023 libgstnvjpeg.so*        
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      0 Aug  3  2023 libgstnvtee.so*   
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      0 Aug  3  2023 libgstnvv4l2camerasrc.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      0 Aug  3  2023 libgstnvvidconv.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      0 Aug  3  2023 libgstnvvideo4linux2.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      0 Aug  3  2023 libgstnvvideosink.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      0 Aug  3  2023 libgstnvvideosinks.so*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14616 Nov 28  2023 libgstofa.so   
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 218136 Jul 26  2022 libgstogg.so   

I tried copying from my local machine all the files to the docker, to replace the empty files, that didn't work.
I tried different images, like pytorch from the same repos and it didn't work aswell.

Fixed my problem using the following docker image as base for my project :
FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/l4t-jetpack:r35.4.1
